# Add -f parameter when running Docker Toolbox

Tags: c#, docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I would like to run a docker container using Docker Compose. The `docker-compose up` command works fine but I want to specify the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file.

This is the command that is working. In this case the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file is `C:\Users\USERNAME\docker-compose.yml`

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" docker-compose up
```

Now when I add the `-f` parameter, the Docker Toolbox just crashes. Say I want to put the file under `C:\docker-compose.yml`

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" docker-compose -f "C:\docker-compose.yml" up
```

Why I need this is because I would dock a Neo4j image using C# code and I am trying to make this string work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using BASH so you need to use Linux-style paths - `c:\app` becomes `/c/app`. Try:

```
...docker-compose -f /c/docker-compose.yml
```

The [start script in Docker Toolbox](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/windows/start.sh) just passes through your arguments to BASH, it doesn't do any syntax conversion from Windows.